# SP.Response.UI doesn't work for Oslo masterpage

Tags: pnp-powershell, office-dev-pnp

I have provisioned a site and have set it up to use the SP.Responsive.UI (PNP).
But what i noticed is when its switched to the Oslo masterpage it breaks the site and the OOTB menus and context menu stopped working

Has anyone experience this and any ideas how to fix this?
Thanks in advance

See error below

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'cloneNode' of null at Object.setUpToggling (SP-Responsive-UI.js:195) at Object.init (SP-Responsive-UI.js:118) at responsiveStartup (SP-Responsive-UI.js:299) at eval (eval at ProcessOnLoadFunctionNames (init.js?rev=XhcVShqV%2FkUCdcpWykXmOA%3D%3DTAG0:1), <anonymous>:1:43) at ProcessOnLoadFunctionNames (init.js?rev=XhcVShqV%2FkUCdcpWykXmOA%3D%3DTAG0:1) at ProcessDefaultOnLoad (init.js?rev=XhcVShqV%2FkUCdcpWykXmOA%3D%3DTAG0:1) at NotifyEventAndExecuteWaitingJobs (init.js?rev=XhcVShqV%2FkUCdcpWykXmOA%3D%3DTAG0:1) at NotifyScriptLoadedAndExecuteWaitingJobs (init.js?rev=XhcVShqV%2FkUCdcpWykXmOA%3D%3DTAG0:1) at $_global_core (core.js?rev=cirE17cPtkMjQL7%2F4SQ%2BAg%3D%3DTAG0:1) at core.js?rev=cirE17cPtkMjQL7%2F4SQ%2BAg%3D%3DTAG0:1
```

Answer (score 0):

In all demos I have seen at MSFT events, i have only seen the Seattle MasterPage used when PNPResponsiveUI has been applied.  This may be the reason why.

Comment: thanks aka fritz. I came across https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Tools/issues/138.It seems there is a fix